# Resolving InstancePerHttpRequest inside "Singleton"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm trying to start using dependency injection inside an existing MVC4 app. I've installed Autofac 3.1.1 and Autofac MVC4 integration 3.1.0. I've been really pleased with it so far - however, I'm having difficulty with request scoping a disposable service:

```
namespace App_Start
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using Autofac;
    using Autofac.Integration.Mvc;

    public static class KernelConfig
    {
        private static IContainer Container { get; set; }

        public static void Register()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

            builder.RegisterType<Bar>()
                   .As<IBar>()
                   .InstancePerHttpRequest();

            builder.RegisterType<Foo>()
                   .As<Foo>()
                   .SingleInstance();

            Container = builder.Build();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(Container));
        }


        class Foo
        {
            private readonly IBar _bar;

            public Foo(IBar bar)
            {
                _bar = bar;
            }
        }

        interface IBar
        {
            void DoStuff();
        }

        class Bar : IBar, IDisposable
        {
            public void DoStuff() { }

            public void Dispose() { }
        }
    }
}
```

If I request an instance of IBar in a controllers constructor, everything works as expected - a new Bar is made every time and destroyed everytime. However, if I request a Foo in my controllers constructor I get the following message:

> "No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the
>   scope in which the instance was requested"

As far as I can work out, Autofac is creating a new Foo as a singleton. While this may seem obvious (I requested it to be a singleton) I would expect Autofac to walk the dependency tree and use the same lifetime across the entire tree. (I.e. if a singleton contains a transient, then both should be transient)

Is this the expected behaviour? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A singleton cannot contain a transient.
The container will not differ from the configured life cycle based on one consumer, as a dependency can have multiple consumers. 
If a dependency is to be used by a singleton, it should itself be configured as a singleton .
A transient can of course use the singleton dependency as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dependency to *IBarFactory* instead of *IBar*. *IBarFactory* will have sigleton lifestyle and it will return *IBar* instance, which will be resolved from container.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown because the code is trying to resolve an InstancePerHttpRequest object within a single instance object.

With some modifications you can achieve this.

1. Convert Foo to accept Func

```
public class Foo {
    private readonly Func _barFunc;

    public Foo(Func barFunc) {
        _barFunc = barFunc;
    }
}
```

2. Use DependencyResolver.Current object to resolve Func

```
builder.Register(c => new Foo(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService()))
   .As()
   .SingleInstance();
```

For more tips on Autofac scope, check out this link
[Autofac per request scope](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html)